# Sitecore WFM - Show/Hide form fields based on field value?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

I'm currently using the WFM module in Sitecore to display a form full of fields in sections.

I'm trying to do the following:

- Use "Layout Rules" to show/hide a section of fields, depending on checkbox value

When I try to use the Layout Rules on the section I want to hide/show, it doesn't seem to be working (everything is showing).

I've put in the following logic:

- NEW CONDITION
- where HotelAmenitiesCheckbox field IS NOT EQUAL TO 1
- hide element

'HotelAmenitiesCheckbox' is a checkbox field in the form. I've set the name and DisplayName in Sitecore to be exactly what I've typed above.

Can anyone help explain which direction I need to go? This is frustrating with my limited knowledge of .NET and Sitecore's limited documentation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and haven't been able to find an out-of-box solution with the WFFM module so I came up with this workaround that leverages the `Help` field of a WFFM field to store a "line of code".  I gave the marketers an `if` statement that they can write in the `Help` field and when the form loads on the front-end, there's some JS that parses that `if` statement and hides/shows fields that are dependent on each other.  I asked this question just this weekend, and got a lot of help from the community here on Stackoverflow: [Conditional Renderings with JavaScript Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118921/conditional-renderings-with-javascript-regex).