# Conditional Renderings with JavaScript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I need to match on a string such as this:

`'if Country equals "United States" then Show'`

I'm working with the Webforms for Marketers Module in Sitecore.  Sitecore is a .NET based CMS.  The Webforms for Marketers Modules is a module that provides a GUI for non-developers to design forms with textboxes, drop-down lists, checkboxes, etc...  I have requirements to only show certain fields on the form if the user picked a certain option in a previous field.  For example: only show the States drop-down list if the user picked "United States" from the Country drop-down list.  The problem is, the WFFM module doesn't support conditional renderings of fields so I'm trying to implement it myself with JavaScript.  My idea is this:

- I'll build out the form in the module with all of the possible fields
- When the page loads, I'll use JavaScript to hide fields that depend on the value of previous fields
- When a user interacts with a field, I'll run some JavaScript to check the value of the field and determine whether or not I should show one or more of the fields that I hid on page load.

I'm basically writing an interpreter for an `if` statement; I'm giving the marketers a way to "program" the form.  `Country` is the name of a drop-down list on my page.  `equals` is a condition.  `"United States"` is one of the values in drop-down list.  If the user picks `United States` in the drop-down, `then` `Show` the States drop-down list.

So the input for the regex test would always follow this format:

- always starts with the keyword `if`
- followed by 1 or more white-spaces
- followed by any number of digits, and/or letters and/or white-spaces

  - The name of controls can contain more than one word with spaces and even numbers

    - For example: First Name, or, Address Line 1
- followed by 1 or more white-spaces
- followed by the keyword `equals`
- followed by 1 or more white-spaces
- followed by 1 double-quote
- followed by any number of digits, and/or letters and/or white-spaces

  - The value of the control can contain more than one word with spaces and even numbers
- followed by 1 double-quote
- followed by 1 or more white-spaces
- followed by the keyword `then`
- followed by either the keyword `Show` or the keyword `Hide`

I've got this much that works but it's not all of the requirements I've listed above.  This line matches all the way up to the white-space after the control name.

`var pattern = /^if\s+(\d*|\w*)\s+.*$/;`

But when I try to match on the double-quote it doesn't work; I don't really know the syntax for matching on the double-quote.  I've tried all of the following, none work:

`var pattern = /^if\s+(\d*|\w*)\s+["].*$/;`

`var pattern = /^if\s+(\d*|\w*)\s+\".*$/;`

`var pattern = /^if\s+(\d*|\w*)\s+\"{1}.*$/;`

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I recommend against allowing marketers to make web forms.

Comment: @zzzzBov - I recommend against allowing marketers to make _anything_.

Comment: @nnnnnn - LOL if only I had that option!

Comment: @Barbosa I was wondering if you could add more details about how you actually got this working?

Comment: @ADH this was my attempt at writing a "rules engine" for Webforms for Marketers.  Keep in mind, this was 4 years ago!  If you're working with the latest version of Sitecore and WFFM, I recommend you look at the built-in features available now.  Here's an example.  I haven't tried it myself but this might be the built-in way of doing what I was trying to do manually 4 years ago - http://zacharykniebel.com/blog/sitecore/2014/june/04/dynamic-form-fields-in-6-steps-in-wffm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest an expression like this:

```
/^if\s+([\w\s]+)\s+equals\s+"([\w\s]*)"\s+then\s+(\w*)$/
```

Which you could use like this:

```
var expression = // set this to your input
var matches = expression.match(/^if\s+([\w\s]+)\s+equals\s+"([\w\s]*)"\s+then\s+(\w*)$/);

if (matches) { // if matches isn't null
    // matches[1] is the field name
    // matches[2] is the value in quotes
    // matches[3] is the operation to perform
```

I haven't hardcoded "Hide" and "Show" into the regex - instead it returns whatever string is after "then". I figured that would make it easier to add more operations later. If you want to hardcode these operation names just change the final `(\w*)` to `(Hide|Show)`. Also this expression will work if the part in quotes is an empty string, which may be valid for some field values.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2UFHN/1/

Note: You said _"any number of digits, and/or letters and/or white-spaces" - for that you just need `[\w\s]+`. In your expressions you had `(\d*|\w*)\s+`, which means "zero or more digits OR zero or more word characters FOLLOWED BY by one or more spaces". \w already matches digits (as well as a-z and underscore), so you don't need \d as well.

You *might* want to add an `i` flag to your expression, as in `/expressionhere/i` to make it case insensitve.

Comment: P.S. You might want to ignore leading and trailing whitespace too.

Comment: `[\w\s]+` should be `[\d\w\s]+`.

Comment: @ebohlman - No it shouldn't. As I mentioned in my answer, `\w` _already_ matches digits, so including `\d` is redundant.

Comment: My bad, but `\w` also matches underscores, so to be pedantic it should be `[\da-zA-Z\s]+` (would be nice if JS regexes included POSIX character classes so it would work for non-English languages).

Comment: @ebohlman - Yes, you're right about the underscores. I left `\w` in my answer because the OP had used it, but I did mention the underscores just to make sure OP knew they'd match too.

Comment: Thanks so much for your ideas!  Can I just make one small change?  Instead of `'if Country equals "United States" then Show'`, I'd like to wrap the control name, Country in curly-braces.  The updated `if` statement would look like this: `'if {Country} equals "United States" then Show'`.  I think this will make it easier to match if the Control Name contains white-spaces.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "easier to match", because the regex I've given you already does that - test it out with the demo I provided. But if you want to add curly braces I guess something like this should work: `/^if\s+\{([\w\s]+)\}\s+equals\s+"([\w\s]*)"\s+then\s+(\w*)$/` (If I've gotten it a bit wrong or it needs further tweaking I'd suggest reading up [MDN's regex page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).)

Comment: @nnnnnn - didn't mean to suggest your answer doesn't work for me; it worked perfectly!  I was more thinking about the marketers - that it would be easier for them to understand the syntax if the control name was a little more identified by being wrapped in curly braces, that's all.  thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just use "; no need to escape it.

Also, you're apparently trying to match the " without first matching the `equals`, so it won't match any of your test cases.

```
/^if\s+(\d*|\w*)\s+".*$/.test("if abc \"xyz\"") // ==> true
/^if\s+(\d*|\w*)\s+".*$/.test("if abc equals \"xyz\"") // ==> false
```