# Java conditional regex

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I have such text:

```
120.65UAH Produkti Kvartal
5*14 14:24
Bal. 16603.52UAH
```

What I want to do:
If this text contains "5*14", I need to get 16603.52 via one java reg exp.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118921/conditional-renderings-with-javascript-regex)

[and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022635/i-would-like-to-mimick-conditionals-in-javascript-regex)

[and this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html)

I tried to create conditional regexp like this:

```
(5*14 ([\d\.*]+)UAH)
(5*14 d{2}:d{2} Bal. ([\d\.*]+))
```

etc

But no luck, can you please share your th

Comment: You've tagged this question with both Java and JavaScript. Which is it? They're not interchangeable.

Comment: ["Java and Javascript are similar like Car and Carpet are similar."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)

Comment: Try [`\b5\*14\b[\s\S]*?\b(\d+\.\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/lI4vY9/1). This should work in both JS and Java (with appropriate escaping). If that does not work for you, please clarify your question (add more requirements, what is static what is dynamic in the input, etc.)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I prefer "like ham and hamster."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(\d*\.\d\d)(?>\w*)$
```

will match a group on the last set of DDDDD.DD in the line. You will need to take the contents of the first matching group.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex like this:

```
(?=5\*14)[\s\S]*?(\d{5}\.\d{2})
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/uI7wF3/1)**

[image]

Update: you even don't need the look ahead, you can just use:

```
5\*14[\s\S]*?(\d{5}\.\d{2})
```

Comment: The alternative to the `[\s\S]` trick is to make `.` match newlines: `(?s)5\*14.*?(\d{5}\.\d{2})`

Answer (score 0):

If you have `5*14` *before* the float number you need to get, you can just use

```
(?s)\\b5\\*14\\b.*?\\b(\\d+\\.\\d+)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lI4vY9/3). The value will be in Group 1. I also used Java escaping style.

Note that `5\*14` can match in `145*143` that is why I am using word boundaries `\b`. `.*?` with `(?s)` matches any number of any symbols but as few as possible. `\d+\.\d+` matches simple float number (irrespective of the number of digits there are in it).

[IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/zx6uAs):

```
String str = "120.65UAH Produkti Kvartal\n5*14 14:24\nBal. 16603.52UAH";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("(?s)\\b5\\*14\\b.*?\\b(\\d+\\.\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Result: `16603.52`